Layout compose view without adding to window android
Was looking to capture a bitmap from a view, by measuring, laying out and drawing it on a canvas like so:
public static Bitmap createBitmapFromView(View view) {
  view.measure(
      MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
      MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
  Bitmap bitmap =
      Bitmap.createBitmap(
          view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
  Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
  view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());
  view.draw(c);
  return bitmap;
}

However if any of the internal view is ComposeView it won't layout since it needs to be attached to a window. Is there any workaround to trigger the composition without adding it a window? Moreover I wanted to get this bitmap without access to any Activity
